# outputting an array with a function C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm outputting a two-dimensional array with a `for` loop like this:

```
int output(int data[50][8], string names[50]) {
    int amount = 0;
    amount = fillAndDisplay(data, names);`

    for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
        cout << names[i] << " ";

        for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
            cout << data[i][j] << " ";
        }

        cout << endl;

    }

    return data, names;
}
```

`amount` will equal 5 in my case.

Now, right now I'm returning `data` and `names`, but it's not working. What do I need to return? Also, what data type should I use for the function? I'm using `int` right now, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Here's my full code. The file that it's reading in is:

```
5 
Franks,Tom 2 3 8 3 6 3 5 
Gates,Bill 8 8 3 0 8 2 0 
Jordan,Michael 9 10 4 7 0 0 0 
Bush,George  5 6 5 6 5 6 5 
Heinke,Lonnie  7 3 8 7 2 5 7
```

Here's the code:

```
int fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], string names[50]);

void sort(int data[50][8], string names[50]);

void output(int data[50][8], string names[50]);

int main()
{

int data[50][8];

string names[50];

int amount = 0;


 amount = fillAndDisplay(data, names);

 sort(data, names);

 output(data, names);

system("pause");
return 0;

}

int fillAndDisplay(int data[50][8], string names[50]) {

int const TTL_HRS = 7;
ifstream fin;
fin.open("empdata.txt");

if (fin.fail()) {
    cout << "ERROR";
}

int sum = 0;
int numOfNames;
fin >> numOfNames;

for (int i = 0; i < numOfNames; i++) {

    fin >> names[i];

    data[i][7] = 0;

    for (int j = 0; j < 7; j++) {
        fin >> data[i][j];
        data[i][TTL_HRS] += data[i][j];
    }
}

return numOfNames;

}

void sort(int data[50][8], string names[50]) {

int amount = 0;
int temp = 0;
bool hasSwapped = true;
string tempName;

amount = fillAndDisplay(data, names);

while (hasSwapped) {

    hasSwapped = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < amount - 1; ++i)
    {
        if (data[i][7] < data[i + 1][7]) {

            for (int j = 0; j <= 7; j++) {

                temp = data[i][j];
                data[i][j] = data[i + 1][j];
                data[i + 1][j] = temp;
            }
            tempName = names[i];
            names[i] = names[i + 1];
            names[i + 1] = tempName;

            hasSwapped = true;

        }

    }
}
}

void output(int data[50][8], string names[50]) {

int amount = 0;
amount = fillAndDisplay(data, names);

for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) {
    cout << names[i] << " ";

    for (int j = 0; j < 8; j++) {
        cout << data[i][j] << " ";
    }

    cout << endl;

}


}
```

When The code to print out the arrays is in a function it prints out:

```
Franks,Tom 2 3 8 3 6 3 5 30
Gates,Bill 8 8 3 0 8 2 0 29
Jordan,Michael 9 10 4 7 0 0 0 30
Bush,George 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 38
Heinke,Lonnie 7 3 8 7 2 5 7 39
Press any key to continue . . .
```

but when the code is just in main it prints out

```
Heinke,Lonnie 7 3 8 7 2 5 7 39
Bush,George 5 6 5 6 5 6 5 38
Jordan,Michael 9 10 4 7 0 0 0 30
Franks,Tom 2 3 8 3 6 3 5 30
Gates,Bill 8 8 3 0 8 2 0 29
Press any key to continue . . .
```

Which is what it should print out.

Comment: You don't need to return anything. Since arrays decay to pointers, when passed as parameters, whatever the caller passed will contain the updated values.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik when I make it a void function it still doesn't work

Comment: Define "doesn't work".

Comment: the function is supposed to output 5 strings of data. The data has already been sorted from biggest to smallest. It works fine when It's not in a function, but when it is it outputs the data in the wrong order.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the question asked: "what do I return". What the function returns or doesn't return bears no relevance on what happens before the function returns anything, or what's passed into the function. Your question cannot be answered because it fails to meet stackoverflow.com's requirements for a [mcve].

Comment: but when I just have it in main it works fine so it must have to do with the function right?

Comment: No answer can be given without a [mcve]. It shouldn't take long for me to produce a simple example where looking at a single, isolated function, everything appears to be fine, but it crashes due to memory corruption that occurs previously. Just because some function crashes or doesn't work right doesn't mean that's where the bug is. Welcome to C++.

Comment: @Ralf: you keep saying it "doesn't work", but you haven't defined what exactly it should be doing when it "does work".  It certainly outputs the array values, but what do you WANT it to return to the caller (if anything)?  You need to define your requirements if you want people to help you.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I updated the question. Hope that helps

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I updated the question

Answer (score -1):

This is an interface function. I wouldn't return anything because nothing is being changed or allocated on the heap. "Amount" is on the stack and it gets deleted when the output function is done. If I ever need to change data on the heap I always change that particular object directly instead of allocated memory I don't need.

I would point to those values that are on the heap already. It doesn't make sense to duplicate the data on the stack, you can just reference the heap if you organize your data in an object. This will allow you to fix and make changes very easily as your software expands. Below is a code written by me, not tested, but the idea is there. You could take it further by making "amount", a member that could access private data for calculations like "data" and "names". myCompany->getAmount(); is much easier to read and you can use it whenever you want later on.

```
#ifndef MyHeaderFileH
#define MyHeaderFileH

class Company{
  private:
    int Size;
    int ColCount;
    int *data;
    String *names;

    //This can be public or private. I made it private to clean up my list.
    bool withinRange(int i, int j = 0){

      bool inRange = false;

      if(i >= 0 && i < Size)
        if(j >= 0 && j < ColCount)
          inRange = true;

      return inRange;              
    }

  public:
    //Retrieve data from the heap.
    int getData(int i, int j){
      int Data = 0;

      if(withinRange(i, j))
        Data = data[i][j];

      return Data;
    }
    //UPDATE data on the heap.
    void setData(int Row, int Col, int Data){
      if(withinRange(i, j))
          data[i][j] = Data;
    }
    //Retrieve data from the heap.
    String getNames(int i){
      String Name = "";

      if(withinRange(i, j))
        Name = names[i];

      return Name;
    }
    //UPDATE data on the heap.
    void setNames(i, String Name){
      if(withinRange(i))
          names[i] = Name;
    }

    int importFileData() {

      int const TTL_HRS = 7;
      ifstream fin;
      fin.open("empdata.txt");

      if (fin.fail()) {
        cout << "ERROR";
      }

      int sum = 0;
      int recordCount;
      fin >> recordCount;

      for (int i = 0; i < recordCount; i++) {

        fin >> names[i].c_str(); //or try .w_str();

        data[i][TTL_HRS] = 0;

        for (int j = 0; j < TTL_HRS; j++) {
          fin >> data[i][j];
          //Make a member function that returns the totals for you.
          //data[i][TTL_HRS] += data[i][j];
        }
    }

    return recordCount;

  }

  //Default Constructor
  Company(){
    Size = 50;
    ColCount = 8;
    data = new int[Size][ColCount];
    names = new String[Size];
  }

   /*If you know the size before you create the object you can use this       constructor.*/
  Company(int i, int j){
    Size = i;
    ColCount = j;
    data = new int[Size][ColCount];
    names = new String[Size];
  }

   /*Don't forget to free the memory. This will execute automatically once main() is finished.*/
  ~Company(){
    delete[] data;
    delete[] names;
  }
};

extern Company *myCompany;

#endif

////////////////
//MyCPPFile.cpp
////////////////

void output();
Company *myCompany = new Company; //Calls constructor.

void main(){
    output();
}

void output() {

    for(int r=0; r < myCompany->Size(); r++){
      cout << myCompany->getNames(r) << " ";

      for(int c=0; c < myCompany->ColCount(); c++)  //:P
        cout << myCompany->getData(r, c) << " "; 

      cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Instead of copying the data to the stack you could make the functions below into member functions. You wouldn't even need any parameters because you can access the private data directly from the object.

`public:
    int fillAndDisplay();
    void sort();
    void output();`

Then to use it in your cpp file you would do something like:

`myCompany->sort();`

Comment: Don't try to use `new`, it's too complicated. You have (1) not accounting for the second `new` throwing in the constructor, (2) forgotten to define an adequate Copy and Move Constructors and Assignment Operators => those 2 are solved by using a `std::vector` instead. Furthermore (3) the global does not need to be a pointer: `Company myCompany;` works just fine.

Comment: You don't have to have copy, move, and Assignment operators if you don't need them. It shows how to create a basic data structure. If you just make it a global instead of pointing to it you are using the stack. The benifit of using new makes it so you have one data source and can access it and change it if needed like a database. It's a great solution if you want to access the data globally throughout the entirety of the software. If you are always trying to avoid using new... you are truly missing out on the greatest capabilities that C++ has to offer.

Comment: Regarding Copy/Move: indeed, they are not needed in this *minimal* example, however should the OP copy your code and use it, it will crash badly. Regarding (3): no, you would not be using the stack as this is a global variable, and it will be available globally regardless (though it would be better NOT to use a global, of course). Note that using `std::vector` gives you as much power as using a raw naked array, except it encapsulates all the difficult bits. You don't need to use `new` to have dynamic memory management; you won't miss out anything by using pre-made containers instead.